# Unable to boot raspberry pi from copy of master

Tags: boot, sd-card, cluster

I am following the steps to build a cluster from Southampton uni "[Steps to make Raspberry Pi Supercomputer](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/pi_supercomputer_southampton.htm)" - step 32 and have got to the part where I make a copy of the SD card.

The second Pi doesn't boot at all but if I put either of the two SD cards in the original Pi that it was created on then they boot. So it seems the image is related to the Pi somehow .... any ideas?

Comment: need more info. have you a screen connected to the second Pi, is there any output? do the LED lights on the PCB blink or are they dark all the way?

Comment: Have you tested the second Pi using a clean install of Raspbian on a freshly formatted SD card? My suggestion is to confirm that the second devices is working correctly first.

Comment: If you are sure a pi fails to boot with an SD card that will boot another pi, that pi is broken.  How else can you explain that?  Send it back.

Answer (score 1):

This issue actually ended up being very interesting. I had a brand new Raspberry Pi B and borrowed two other B Pi's from a friend. I had been working on the brand new one and was using an old Raspbian image (2012 I think). I turned out that older images wouldn't boot on my friends Pi's but would on mine (even though they where both Model B). My friends Pi's would only take newer images.

Hope this helps someone in the future and thanks to all the contributors to the original post